# model.save not updating model value

Tags: backbone.js

I am trying to learn Backbone.js and have stuck at an issue. model.save is not updating my model value, though model.fetch updates the value fine.

Please see my code below and let me know if I am doing anything wrong here:

**Model**

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({

    url: "CreatePerson",
    defaults: {
        name: "",
        age: 0
    },
initialize: function(){

this.on("change:name",function(){

        alert("Updated value is: "+this.get("name"));
    });
    }

});
```

I am creating an instance of this model on my html page, below is the code:

```
var person = new Person({name:"manish"});

person.save(person,{

        wait: true,
        success: function(){
            alert("Data saved: "+person.toJSON().name);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("Sorry, something wrong went with the system");
        }       
    });
person.fetch({

        success: function(){
            alert("Data Fetched: "+person.get("name"));
        }
    });
```

On both save and fetch, I am returning the following JSON data from the server:

```
{"name":"Logan","age":23}
```

Interestingly, for save, the change event is not fired and the alert box gives me the old model value (i.e manish), whereas when fetch function executes, the change event is fired and the fetch callback gives me the new value (i.e logan).

Can someone help me in identifying what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Not sure if it's required, but does your server return a status code of `201` (created) for the save (`POST`) request?

Comment: It returns 200, which means that the operation was successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From backbonejs.org

http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save

> Calling save with new attributes will cause a "change" event
>   immediately, and a "sync" event after the server has acknowledged the
>   successful change. Pass {wait: true} if you'd like to wait for the
>   server before setting the new attributes on the model.

Sounds like the server hasn't returned that it is finished.  Removing wait:true should make the changed event trigger.

Comment: Ok. I will try by removing wait = true, though the request was completed. I have debugged using firebug in Mozilla, and have confirmed that the request was completed. Do I need to assign the new values to the model explicitly?

Comment: To be honest i've never used the wait:true attributes on model.save, i'm assuming you maybe have to re poll the server or something?  I know that without wait:true the data in your success(model,response) callback should be the saved data.

Comment: In my success callback, I am not passing model or response. Could that be the reason?

Comment: it could be, though i think backbone provides the objects to the method regardless of whether they are specified in the functions parameters.

Comment: I don't know why, but removing `wait:true` worked. But isn't it a good practice to keep `wait:true` in the code to ensure that the model values are updated only when Server trip has successfully completed?

Comment: to be honest It doesn't really make sense to me since the success callback implies the server finished... successfully.  I've built a few production bb apps and have never used wait:true myself.

Comment: It actually does make sence if validation happens on the server side and you update your views with incorrect data before waiting for the server response.

Comment: @jonezy: It will make sense in the scenario discussed by Andrey. In our application, most of the validations are done on Server side, hence we will need to wait for the validation to complete before modifying the data.

Answer (score 0):

There is error in your code:

```
person.save(person,{
```

You should provide object of attributes to your save call or just the options, but not the model itself. Remove `person,` and check if it works. `wait:true` should be set, to ensure that you change to a proper data validated by server.

Comment: If I want all the attributes of my model to be altered, then should I pass all attributes or pass the model itself?

Comment: Server always gets the whole Backbone model by default, but the save call needs only the attributes that have to be changed (or none, if model already contains changed attributes set by model.set or like in your case model is new so you just need to call save without attributes)